# non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++

I'm sure about my function , but I didn't know the meaning of this error

```
"non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"
```

this is my 
function : recherche d'un trajets dans un vector du trajets

```
int compagnie::rechercher_Trajet(int ind)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tab_Trj.size(); i++)
    {

        if (tab_Trj[i]->getNum == ind)
            return i;
        return -1 ;
    }

}

class  trajets :
    int getNum() { return numero; }
};
```

am asking for your help , thnx

Comment: `getNum` seems to be a function so `if (tab_Trj[i]->getNum() == ind)`.

Comment: thnx i forgot the () ;d

Answer (score 16, accepted):

well...

```
if (tab_Trj[i]->getNum() == ind)
```

you forgot the `()`.

also, in the C++ world, I would advise against writing `for (int...` , prefer `auto` or `size_t` instead of `int`. comparing signed and unsigned values can lead to errors.

PS. it is extremly not common to name entities in your program in a language which is not english. also, you are mixing underscore-convention with lower camel case-convention.

I'd name the function either `rescanTarget` or `rescan_target`, but not `rescan_Target` (which I believe is the translation for "rechercher_Trajet"?).

Comment: thnx for the note and the answer  , but this project is for french teacher .

Comment: Thnx for those precious advices .:)

Comment: still something else i'm confused about something in my project client can reserve for one or more then one train and for one or more then one passager so my question is if i should declare reservation as a function or as a class ?